# KDevelop C++ says i have a missing include file

Tags: cmake, clion, kdevelop, cmakelists-options

I have small (almost hello world) project made with CLion and CMake.
I tried to open it in KDevelop, and it opens, compiles and builds without any problem, the .exe file works aswell.

But why does KDevelop say i need to

[image]

The DataLoader.h is in **/include** folder, and i know i can set it manually in KDevelop settings, but shouldn't every IDE search automatically in **/include** folder when its specified in CMakeLists?

[image]

What I'm trying to exactly do, is make a simple project that I can load in any C++ IDE without having to manually set anything for this project espacially (not talking about paths to mingw cmake etc, but rather current project related problems like this one)

Can i somehow specify in the CMake project to tell the IDE's, that they should automatically look into the **/include** folder?

Answer (score 0):

try to change include_directories with

```
include_direcotries(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
```

Comment: Nothing has changed. I mean, is it problem with the IDE itself? KDevelop developers say that it's awesome to work with CMake projects, so it would be kind of bad if it didnt link additional include directories on it's own from CMake config

Comment: Can you include the file as #include <Dataloader.h>

Comment: It still says it's missing. And i've read online that you should use <> for os headers, not sure if that's true.
If i click on the suggested solution in KDevelop, it includes something like that:
#include <../../../../../../3/include/DataLoader.h>

Also, I've just imported the same project into VSCode and Visual Studio, both did require 0 manual configuration to build and run this project using cmake (not mentioning vscode plugin)

Do you think it might be only KDevelop's issue?

Comment: sorry, but I want to ask you: where is DataLoader.h?

Comment: project_folder/include/DataLoader.h, and the main.cpp and DataLoader.cpp are in the project_folder/src/ .The problem is that Cmake runs without any issue, and Clion,VSC, and Visual Studio see the DataLoader.h perfectly fine, only KDevelop says its missing for some reason. I thought i was doing something wrong in CMakeLists, but maybe it's just kdevelops issue as i see there: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-3876934.html?sid=fbed7b7a3e583c2707c0f1ad92320e92